# Approximating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having trouble with my math assignment that asks me the following:

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ be a series, with $a_n \neq 0$, and suppose that
$$\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} \le r \lt 1,       n\ge0$$

(a) Estimate $|a_n|$ in terms of $|a_0|$ and $r$.
(b) Using the above estimate, show that the sequence of partial sums for the series $\sum|a_n|$ (which
is increasing) is bounded above.
(c) Show that $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

How should I go about answering these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unrollling the condition given, you have $\lvert a_1\rvert \leq r\lvert a_0\rvert$, $\lvert a_2\rvert \leq r\lvert a_1\rvert\leq r^2\lvert a_0\rvert$,  $\lvert a_3\rvert \leq r\lvert a_2\rvert\leq r^3\lvert a_0\rvert$, etc. By induction, which bound can you give on $\lvert a_n\rvert$?
- Using the first part, you can write

  > $$0 \leq \lvert a_n\rvert \leq \lvert a_0\rvert r^n$$

which implies that for all $N\geq 0$

> $$0 \leq \sum_{n=0}^N\lvert a_n\rvert \leq \lvert a_0\rvert\sum_{n=0}^Nr^n$$

which you can in turn upper bound by $\lvert a_0\rvert\sum_{n=0}^N r^n\leq \lvert a_0\rvert\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$, recalling that $0\leq r < 1$. Now, you can compute explicitly the value of the RHS (as a function of $\lvert a_0\rvert, r$) from the formula for geometric series.

- Finally, the previous point exactly implies the last, pretty much by definition and the monotone convergence theorem ($\sum_{n=0}^N\lvert a_n\rvert$ is a bounded non-decreasing sequence, and so must converge).

Answer (score 0):

(a) $|a_n|$ is less than $|a_0|$. Also, no matter how small the ratio $r$ is, when the absolute value of the subsequent term divides this ratio the absolute value of the current term is always larger than it. Therefore, $|a_0|$ will always be larger than $|a_n|$. Therefore, for all $r$,

$$\frac{|a_n|}{r} < |a_0|$$

(b) The ratio bounds the sequence, i.e. each successive term is less than the current one **and** it either decreases faster ($\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ becomes less) or it remains the same (and eventually, at a straight line, hits zero). The sequence is therefore never concave up because the slopes are decreasing. Can you prove this mathematically now?

(c) $\sum{a_n}$ is bounded by at most a triangle.